# The calculator won't display the right results

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to ask a bit of help. I was creating a simple calculator. The problem is my calculator displays the same results everytime. The addition would display nothing, the subtraction and multiplication would display 0, and the division and modulo would display NaN. Here is my code:

```js
let a = document.getElementById("num1").innerHTML;
let b = document.getElementById("num2").innerHTML;

function addFunction() {
  let add = a + b;
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = add;
}

function subtractFunction() {
  let subtract = a - b;
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = subtract;
}

function multiplyFunction() {
  let multiply = a * b;
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = multiply;
}

function divideFunction() {
  let divide = a / b;
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = divide;
}

function moduloFunction() {
  let modulo = a % b;
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = modulo;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>Simple Calculator</h2>
  <p>How to operate: Enter two numbers first in the textboxes. Next, press the button of the respective operand. Lastly, a result will come up under the calculator.</p>
  <input id="num1">
  <input id="num2">
  <br>
  <br>
  <button onclick="addFunction()">+</button>
  <button onclick="subtractFunction()">-</button>
  <button onclick="multiplyFunction()">*</button>
  <button onclick="divideFunction()">/</button>
  <button onclick="moduloFunction()">%</button>
  <p>Result: </p>
  <p id="result">
    <p>
</div>
```

Comment: `innerHTML` is not the correct property to read the current value of a text input field - `value` is. And you can of course not read the field values only once when your script initializes - you need to read the _current_ values, at the time when your calculation functions actually run.

Comment: Ignore the answers, they skip over the requirement to read the current values. Here's a version without inline code and duplicate code: https://jsfiddle.net/qktoxp78/ edit: (lejlun's is somewhat ok but still not best practice)

Answer (score 2):

You should get values of input not innerHTML like this

```
var a = document.getElementById("num1").value
var b = document.getElementById("num2").value
```

And then convert it to number like this

```
a = parseFloat(a)
b = parseFloat(b)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this:

```
let a = parseFloat(document.getElementById("num1").value);
let b = parseFloat(document.getElementById("num2").value);
```

Answer (score -1):

You need `.value` to get the text of the input field, this will return a string so you also need to use the [`Unary Plus (+)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus) to convert it to a number:

```js
+document.getElementById("num1").value;
+document.getElementById("num2").value;
```

Since the content of both input boxes change throughout the program, you would need to run the lines above mulitple times to get the updated content. You can do this with functions:

```js
function getA() {
  return +document.getElementById("num1").value;
}

function getB() {
  return +document.getElementById("num2").value;
}
```

To prevent the user from entering characters that aren't numbers you can also set the input type:

```html
<input id="num1" type="number">
<input id="num2" type="number">
```

**Full code:**

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Simple Calculator</h2>
    <p>How to operate: Enter two numbers first in the textboxes. Next, press the button of the respective operand. Lastly, a result will come up under the calculator.</p>
    <input id="num1" type="number">
    <input id="num2" type="number">
    </br>
    </br>
    <button onclick="addFunction()">+</button>
    <button onclick="subtractFunction()">-</button>
    <button onclick="multiplyFunction()">*</button>
    <button onclick="divideFunction()">/</button>
    <button onclick="moduloFunction()">%</button>
    <p>Result: </p>
    <p id="result">
      <p>
  </div>
  <script>
    function getA() {
      return +document.getElementById("num1").value;
    }

    function getB() {
      return +document.getElementById("num2").value;
    }

    function addFunction() {
      let add = getA() + getB();
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = add;
    }

    function subtractFunction() {
      let subtract = getA() - getB();
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = subtract;
    }

    function multiplyFunction() {
      let multiply = getA() * getB();
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = multiply;
    }

    function divideFunction() {
      let divide = getA() / getB();
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = divide;
    }

    function moduloFunction() {
      let modulo = getA() % getB();
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = modulo;
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Just to explain why you're getting downvoted: your answer is basically a quick fix, but even if this question were a suitable addition to this website (it's not), an answer should use best practices like avoiding inline and duplicate code. See my comment above for a proper solution.